# Get Magento 2 customer ID in Vue front-end

Tags: express, magento, graphql, nuxt.js, vue-storefront

I am working on Vue Storefront ( a Nuxt.js with Express.js based framework) where GraphQL queries are used to get data from Magento 2.

I tried to add customers ID in the GraphQL query for customer data but it returned as Null (see response below). I've read this is not recommended but I still want to try something in my client with the Customer ID.

```
   "data":{
      "customer":{
         "__typename":"Customer",
         "date_of_birth":null,
         "email":"john@doe.com",
         "firstname":"john",
         "is_subscribed":false,
         "id":null,
         "addresses":[
            ...
```

How can I, safety risks aside, still aquire the Customer ID in my front-end? Is there a small GraphQl query I can execute as a javascript function? I also have an Express.js part of my app where I can securely request and send data to other platforms (this is server side).

Comment: Did you tried to look for the GraphQL documentation and try to run the query with Postman or Insomnia? Not an expert on this specific use case but if what you're trying to achieve is feasible, there should be some examples/documentation IMO.

Comment: We're trying to do the same thing. BTW, why is it not recommended?
The customer id was there but it was deprecated https://github.com/magento/graphql-ce/issues/907